# Pages loaded by AJAX from the PHP back-end

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I'm tring to do is to load information from different pages, without having to refresh the whole main page...

Could you tell me how to adapt this code for loading files with different names (like `about.html` and `project.html`?

Note: this code is made just for loading `'page_.html'` files.

---

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){

            checkURL(this.hash);

    });

    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;

        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else
        loadPage(hash);
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#page','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.php",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}
```

---

Here is the php file:

```
if(!$_POST['page']) die("0");

$page = (int)$_POST['page'];

if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
echo file_get_contents('pages/page_'.$page.'.html');

else echo 'There is no such page!';
```

Comment: just prefix your page names with `page_` and make sure they are in the `pages` folder

Comment: I suspect this duplicates your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538369/ajax-error-with-jquery) that was put on hold. However, I think that will re-open now that it has been fixed. For now I will hold off closing this one, but please do not create duplicates in future - it is better to fix a question than to ask it again.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line

```
if(file_exists('pages/page_'.$page.'.html'))
```

with this

```
if(file_exists('pages/'.$page.'.html'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make multiple ajax requests this is the jquery load method:

```
$( "#result" ).load( "ajax/test.html", function() {
  alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

do that 2x and your well off!
Keep in mind for this to work you'll need the jquery library.

I was doing a similar thing on my site here is my code:

```
    window.setInterval("check()",60000); 
//request information notice is inside a function called check() (it's not required to put inside function I only do this if I will be making the same request multiple time throughout the program)                      
                        function check() {
                            var request = $.ajax({
                                url: "file.php",
                                type: "POST",            
                                dataType: "html"
                            });

                            request.done(function(msg) {
//when request is done:
                                $(".wheretoputnewdata").html(msg);          
                            });

                            request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
                                //if request failed do this:
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
                            });
                       }
```